# Compare how many times distinct words appear in inputs C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have been trying different techniques to tackling this problem and I am quite new to C++ or programming in general. This problem comes from a book I'm reading over called "Accelerated C++" and so far I'm only on the 3rd chapter so I'm trying to tackle the problem with only what has been taught in the 3rd chapter. When I run the program it runs fine, but as soon as I input a single word I get a segmentation fault. Could anyone explain to me why that is happening? Also if my ways are extremely inefficient with the knowledge I know so far, hinting towards a better way to do things within the chapter boundaries would be great!

Here is the code:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ios>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //ask for the first sentence to be typed in.
    cout << "Please enter some words: ";
    vector<string> word_storage;
    vector<int> word_count;
    string x;
    int y = 0;

    //words inputed pushed into vector(word_storage) or incremented if they exist
    while(cin >> x) {

        for(int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
            if(x != word_storage[i]) {
                word_storage.push_back(x);
                word_count.push_back(1);
            } else {
                word_count[i] += 1;
            }
        }
        y++;
    }

    cout << endl;

    //get size of word_storage
    typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
    vec_sz size = word_storage.size();

    //system prints how many of each word exist
    for(int j = 0; j <= size; j++) {
        cout << "There are: " << word_count[j]
                << " of the word " << word_storage[j];
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I apologize in advanced for the eye-sore coding.

Comment: If you're using gcc, you can link with symbols and then run the program through `gdb`. When it crashes, you can examine the callstack. I can see you're trying to count how many times a word appears consecutively, rather than distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors contain their own size.  I believe you've probably got two bugs.  First, you the '<=' in your for loop is going to walk off the end of the vector, it should be '<'.  Second, you're iterating y when you're not adding words to word_storage.

I think you're find part should look more like:

```
while(cin >> x) {
    for(int i = 0; i < word_storage.size(); i++) {
        if(x != word_storage[i]) {
            word_storage.push_back(x);
            word_count.push_back(1);
        } else {
            word_count[i] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

There are also a few other improvements that could be made, not the least of which would be to use a structure to tie the storage and the count to the same vector, and using iterators.  Consider that when you get to those chapters.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        if(x != word_storage[i]) {
```

`word_storage` is an unintialized/empty vector. And you are trying to access on a empty vector is causing segmentation fault. As an example, at the beginning of the loop, there is nothing in the vector to do an subscript operation on it.

Do the `[]` operation on the `word_storage`, if it's size is greater than `i`.